# How to concatenate cells in a row until the first blank cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm currently diving into code/VBA coding for the first time. I have a file that I dump into a worksheet that currently I'm manually organizing and pushing out. When put into the worksheet, it delimits itself across the cells. The first 2-4 cells are always parts of a name. This dump file will have varying row and column lengths every time I get it in a given day and dump into a work sheet. For example, one day it may be twenty rows and one day it may be thirty.

This is a rough illustration of what the data looks like, but my code probably doesn't match with the example below - I just wanted to provide a visual:

[image: screenshot of the spreadsheet, showing current vs desired result]

So, I'm wanting to make code that will start at A1 and concatenate the cells following it until it runs into a blank cell in that row. Then it places the concatenated data into cell A1 and removes the values it pulled the name pieces from and slides all the data to the left. After that, it continues the same operation on the next row until it meets the final row. As you can see in the image, I don't want any of the data after the blank cell to be affected.

This is my first time programming in general, so when you provide assistance, would you please explain your code so I can learn the concepts? Here's what I think will work so far... I'm just stuck on how to go about concatenating.

The code I currently have:

```
Sub DN_ERROR_ORGANIZER()
  Dim row As Integer
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xldown)).Rows.Count
  Range("A1").Select
  For row = 1 To NumRows
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
          ' Code to concatenate
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
End sub
```

Comment: Seems the row for John Doe would end up being "Doe, John Data" given your data.

Comment: You're able to find the last cell on your formula. You can use what this guy have done to convert it to a concatenate formula. https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/concatenate-range-of-cells/

Comment: @Mat'sMug The type of coding I'm wanting to do would stop at the first occurrence of a blank cell. For Row 2, the code would do A2 + ", " + B2 + " " + C2, stop at C2 because D2 is a blank cell, put what the loop has so far into A2, remove whatever was originally in A2, B2, and C2 , shifting cells to the left, and proceeding to do the same operation on the next row. For Row 3, the code would instead do A3 + ", " + B3, stop at B3 because C3 is a blank cell, put what the loop has so far into A3, remove whatever was originally in A3 and B3, shifting cells to the left, and proceeding to next row.

Comment: Got it. You'll definitely want to avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to look at your problem: Suppose you have your table on Sheet2, and the result is reflected on Sheet1.

```
Sub PutInOrder()
  filledcells = 0
  '''lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To 100
     If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For 
     For a = 1 To 4
        If Sheet2.Cells(i, a) = "" Then Exit For
          If Sheet2.Cells(i, a) <> "" Then
             filledcells = filledcells + 1
        End If
    Next

Select Case filledcells
    Case Is = 2

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) + ", " + Sheet2.Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 4)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 7)


    Case Is = 3

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) + ", " + Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) + " " + Sheet2.Cells(i, 3)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 7)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 8)


    Case Is = 4

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) + ", " + Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) + " " + Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) + " " + Sheet2.Cells(i, 4)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 7)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 8)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 9)

   End Select
   filledcells = 0
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: You made the code seem a whole lot less complex than how I was originally approaching it. Though, what are the purposes of the rows below the cat row of each case? Also I get a "Run-time error '424': Object required" for the row with "lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row". Could you walk me through what your declaring lastRow to do so that I may try and troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: lejaregg, The line -

Comment: lejaregg, The line "lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row" counts the number of rows that contain data, nothing much. I assumed the data was on a different sheet and you needed the result reflected on some other sheet. So the code above looks up data on Sheet2. And, for the code to work without producing error messages, it should be obvious that Sheet2 should have some data). By the way, I could not make out your question: " what are the purposes of the rows below the "cat" row of each case?" However, let me say that the code in the Select Case puts your data where you want it.

Comment: Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 4)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 7)

Comment: lejaregg, The code you put up in your comment puts 4 cells of data from sheet2 into cells on Sheet1 beginning with column C . As in this example your data is spread from Column D Column to Column I, The Select Case decides which data from Sheet2 to put in cells on Sheet1 beginning with a cell in Column C through F.

Comment: Vasant, I'm sorry - please disregard my comment above. I accidentally sent that prematurely without realizing it. Thanks for the explanation, I understand now. Though, I can't seem to figure out the error though with the line "lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row". I've tried adding Sheet2.Rows.Count, I've tried wrapping it in a with statement, but it comes back to the same error of "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: lejaregg, To avoid the error message, do this: comment or remove this line - "lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row". Then remove the variable 'lastrow' in the following line and make the For loop to run, say, a 100 times (i.e. For i=1 to 100) , and add this line of code below- "If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For" to get out of unnecessary looping. Here, the figure 100  purely arbitrary, you can write any number, if you like. Now, I suppose this should save you from facing "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: I tried this change in code and it just highlights the "If Sheet2.Cells(i, a) <> "" " in the debugger instead with the same error. I double checked to ensure my data is in Sheet2 and still the error persists.

Comment: lejaregg, I'm sorry that my little simple code is giving you hiccups, and I must earn my points. Now do this, please: Go to Sheet2 and enter your data in the range A1:I5. Copy another version of the same answer you'll find here in a short while. Run it. And I pray that it'll work this time... Else, I'll put up another variation of this code.

Comment: Vasant, unfortunately still producing the same issue and debug highlight. I decided to wrap everything in a "With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet", remove the identifiers like Sheet2 in front of everything, and declare row and col counters. It seems to be working fine. I will award you the points for your persistence, patience and for providing me with a legible code and walk through of the code to where I figured out and solved the issue on my own thanks to your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and let me know how you get on? It may need some tweaks depending on your precise layout. My approach is slightly different.

```
 Sub x()

Dim n As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, v

For n = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r1 = Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas(1)
    Set r2 = Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas(2)
    If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing Then
        v = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r1)), ", ")
        Cells(n, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(v)
        Cells(n, 2).Resize(, r1.Count).Clear
        r2.Cut Cells(n, 3)
    End If
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a run-time error '1004': No cells were found. When going into the debugger it highlights the 1st row in your for loop?

Comment: I have amended code above. As mentioned, the error is probably due to your layout which may be different from what I assumed (data in A1 down and across).

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't do anything at all now. But, you are correct in assuming the format - it is that way.

Comment: I've just tested it on data as set in your pic and it works fine. Your actual layout must be different? I don't think you can post files here (?) but perhaps you can upload a sample somewhere else and link?

Comment: I apologize, I should of represented all of the data that should be showing. This more accurately represents what all I have. http://i.imgur.com/2a1T1gY.jpg

Comment: That is a completely different kettle of fish. I can't see any blank cells.

Comment: I manually made up that sample data. I apologize, please assume there is a blank cell after the last name piece. I also forgot to say that my current code removes (EXT) before this code I'm trying to do to produce the blank cell after the last name piece.

Comment: Have you got a solution you're happy with now, or do you want me to pursue this? If so, for the avoidance of doubt please post a shot of a sample exactly as is.

Comment: With a combination of yours and the answer I select I was able to come up with my own code. Thank you for helping!